# Center text inside column on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling to get some text centered in a section of my page (with class `about`) in the mobile view. Note everything is inside a div with class `container-fluid`. Also there was an issue with this section where blank space was appearing on the sides, which wasn't being filled in with background color (fixed for now by adding that color to the body, but I'm thinking whatever caused that is related). I would like it to instead fill 80% of the width of the screen.

[image: Result]

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/PaNjLW)

HTML (affected section):

```
        <section class="about" id="about">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <h2>About</h2>
            </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <img src="img/circle-portrait-small.png" class="portrait">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <p>.....</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

CSS:

```
.about {
  padding: 3em 0;
}

.about p {
  text-align: left;
  width: 80%;  

}

/* Not sure why this is needed */
.about .row {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .about {
    padding: 2em;
  }

  .about p {
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  .portrait {
    height: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random space looks like it's caused by negative margins set on your `row` element:

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Remove this and you should lose the space. For the centering of the paragraph on mobile, it seems your `p` element is already taking up 80% of its parent, so to center it just add the following:

```
.about p {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Visually, it looks like your `p` elements are taking up far less than 80% width of their parent after your 767px breakpoint, and that's because you have padding set on your `col`, `about` and `container-fluid` elements. Remove or reduce this padding at your breakpoint and the paragraphs will begin to take up the space you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

add this below css in mobile only

```
.about .row {
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: table;
}
.about p {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [update code](https://codepen.io/caseydev/pen/vrGpVJ?editors=1100)

You can remove unnecessary `margin` or `width`

Answer (score 0):

There's various problems with the markup.

- The first row tag isn't properly closed.
- The extra about CSS is limiting the with of the text to 80%;

Remove this...

```
/* Not sure why this is needed */
.about .row {
  width: 100%;
}
.about p {
  text-align: left;
  width: 80%;  
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/fXFvL2644p

If you're going to use Bootstrap grid, carefully follow the appropriate structure of `container`>`row`>`col(s)`.